# Why don't all Absolute,X instructions take an extra cycle to cross page boundaries?

Tags: 6502

The question is about 6502 instructions that take an extra cycle when address calculation carries over into the high byte of the address. This affects addressing modes Absolute,X, Absolute,Y, Indirect,Y. I suppose it also affects the relative branches. I'm going to call such a cycle a penalty cycle (I have seen this term in various emulator source code, and there's no better words I can think of).

Going from [this document](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html), Many instructions take a penalty cycle to manipulate the high byte of the effective address, denoted by a `+` in the last column. Initially, I thought that *all* opcodes that needed to do this incurred a penalty cycle. But the general pattern seems to be that if it needs to write something to memory, then it doesn't incur a penalty cycle.

Why is this? Can the high byte of the effective address sometimes somehow be incremented for free? I don't see how, because the 6502 uses its ALU to generate the carry, and also to add the carry into the high byte.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The CPU needs to do an addition of the 2-byte address after the opcode and the 8-bit unsigned displacement from `X` or `Y` register.

Since 6502 addresses are always stored as little-endian, the CPU gets the lower byte first. During the time it reads the following higher byte, it simultaneously performs addition of the lower byte just read and the contents of the index register.

If that addition results in no carry, the CPU instantly knows it does not need to update the high byte of the address. Therefore the read cycle at the correct address follows (no penalty).

When there is carry, the 6502 needs another cycle to increment the high byte of the address. During that process, the 6502 does a dummy read cycle at the incorrect address, followed by the correct read cycle (penalty).

It is obvious that there should be no 'dummy' *write* cycles at incorrect addresses. Therefore the 6502 always takes a 'penalty' *read* cycle with an (probably) incorrect address before performing the final write.

Interesting enough, the little-endianness of the 6502 made such a cycle-saving possible. Were there big-endianness, like in the 6805, there would *always* be a penalty in index addressing, as it happens in the 6805 itself.

So, unlike, for example, the 8080 and Z80, here the endianness actually did matter.

Comment: Sequenced processing of multi word values is the basic idea of why little endian storage is used at all. Machines that doe only use word size data (and a word sized memory interface) do not gain from inverting the sequence.

Comment: @Raffzahn if they only use word-sized data and a word-sized memory interface, *is* there a sequence? It would be like talking about the endianness of bits within each byte

Comment: @user253751: If a machine like the Intel 8088 performs "inc word [addr]", it will read the lower and upper bytes at the destination address, compute the new value, and then write both the lower and upper bytes without regard for whether both had actually changed.

Comment: @supercat That's because the Intel 8088 doesn't only operate on word-sized data through a word-sized memory interface

Comment: @user253751 That's exactly the point why little endian only makes sense for an architecture working on multiple words. Everywhere else it doesn't matter, so big endian can be used easing at least dump reading :)

Comment: It might make sense, but not always. 8080 and Z80 don't gain anything from little-endianness.

Comment: @lvd: Multi-precision arithmetic, whether processed in hardware or user code, can generally be done most efficiently in little-endian sequence.  For some architectures, doing things in ascending or descending sequence of addresses would be equally easy, but for many others ascending would be easier, and for some descending may be easier.  I find it odd that compilers targeting 8032 tend to use big-endian even though the architecture is agnostic to ordering, but the presnce of "INC DPTR" but no "DEC DPTR" would favor processing data in ascending address order.

Comment: @lvd Well, IIRC neither does address arithmetic nor adding of 16 bit values from memory, so there is nothing to gain within the instruction set.

Comment: @supercat well, doing multiple-precision arithmetic at big-endian is not hard: just keep pointers to the LAST word. 8051 stores 16-bit addresses in big-endian order (like in `LCALL` or in `LJMP` or in `MOV DPTR,#imm`), that might be the cause.

Comment: @lvd: The 8051 has an `INC DPTR` instruction, but no corresponding `DEC DPTR` instruction.  Thus, if a value is stored little-endian and one starts with its address in r5:r4 and, one could e.g. add r3:r2 via `mov dpl,r4 / mov dph,r5 / movx a,@dptr / add a,r2 / movx @dptr,a / inc dptr / movx a,@dptr / adc a,r3 / movx @dptr,a`.  Storing big-endian means it's necessary to reload DPTR from r5:r4 between processing the low-order and high-order byte.

Comment: Yes, I see. I'm speaking about what could actually make compiler writers to store multibyte quantities as big-endian on 8051.

Comment: @lvd: The only situation where the 8051 writes or reads a 16-bit value is when performing or returning from a call or interrupt.  The order of the two bytes on the stack places the PC high  byte at the lower address, but I see no reason for compilers to care about that.

Comment: well, it is the situation it reads from internal memory (128 or 256 bytes). Still another case of reading 16-bit values from program memory is 3-byte commands with 16-bit immediate values as I pointed in a comment above. Those 16-bit immediate values are stored as big-endian numbers.

Comment: @lvd: The order of bits or bytes within an instruction doesn't always need to coincide with the order of bytes for memory operands.  When processing AJMP, putting the bottom 8 bits of the target address in the second byte of the instruction would make more sense than trying to put the bottom 3 bits within the opcode byte, even if the architecture were observably little-endian.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR: It's always included.

---

If you compare the timing of memory writing using Absolute,X (ASL, DEC, INC, LSR, ROL, ROR, STA) or Absolute,Y (STA) with their counterpart using Absolute (without indexing), you'll note that the additional cycle is always included. It's only 'optional' for reading instructions.

Example from the ([original](http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html)) table (abreviated):

```
AND (bitwise AND with accumulator)

MODE           SYNTAX       HEX LEN TIM
Zero Page     AND $44       $25  2   3
Zero Page,X   AND $44,X     $35  2   4
Absolute      AND $4400     $2D  3   4
Absolute,X    AND $4400,X   $3D  3   4+
Absolute,Y    AND $4400,Y   $39  3   4+

+ add 1 cycle if page boundary crossed


ASL (Arithmetic Shift Left)

MODE           SYNTAX       HEX LEN TIM
Zero Page     ASL $44       $06  2   5
Zero Page,X   ASL $44,X     $16  2   6
Absolute      ASL $4400     $0E  3   6
Absolute,X    ASL $4400,X   $1E  3   7
```

Making the page crossing cycle optional is an optimization only added to reading instructions, so they are the exception here.

Comment: On the original 6502, the repeated read is optional when it would be the last cycle before the next instruction fetch.  Read-modify-write instructions could have skipped the repeated read when there is a page crossing, but that would require having a means of skipping a state within the instruction.

Comment: Why do you say the document hosted on 6502.org is the original?

Comment: @OmarL because, to my knowledge it is.